# Reuse UIControl subclass with the design made in IB

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uicontrol

I have subclassed UIControl to create my custom control, but I have designed it using Interface Builder. Now I want to "export" it and use it for another application and I don't know exactly what I should do in order to be able to reuse it. It loads using initWithCoder.

I have searched quite a bit on the Internet, but I haven't find a right answer for my question.

Thank you.

Comment: .m file, .h file and .xib file? no?

Comment: Actually I used Storyboard when I developed this custom control. But if I would do it again in a xib  file, would I be able to use it in a application that uses Storyboard? So I have the the .m file and the .h file and the Storyboard.

Comment: I didn't work with storyBoard but i think there should be an option to select a class of your control like in IB.

Comment: Yes, I can select a custom class, but in that custom class (myCustomControl.h) I only have the logic of my control, I don't have the drawings. So what happens to the drawings?

Comment: It will use `myCustomControl.xib` if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need use the following code in viewDidLoad of ViewController method:

```
CustomControl *control = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomControl" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
control.frame = CGRectMake(5.0f, 0.0f, 310.0f, 180.0f);
[self.view addSubview:control];
```

Comment: Which means I should develop my whole application using .xib files, and not the Storyboard?

Comment: I think yes. And using StroyBoard is just for iOS 5. But there are many devices with iOS 4.